# I want to show the total price and total payment amount of the products I pulled from the database to this button. how can I do that?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a button in flutter or dart languages ​​for the total price of the products I pulled from the database and show this button the total payment amount. how can I do that ?

```
Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            //   height: 100,
                            width: 150,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                            child: CustomButton(
                            btnTxt: getTranslated('total_amount', context),
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

          ),
          ),
```

My Custom button here,

```
 class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  final String btnTxt;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Icon icon;
  CustomButton({this.onTap, @required this.btnTxt, this.backgroundColor, this.icon});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
      backgroundColor: onTap == null ? ColorResources.getGreyColor(context) : backgroundColor == null ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor : backgroundColor,
      minimumSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 50),
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    );

    return TextButton(
      onPressed: onTap,

      style: flatButtonStyle,
      child:
      Text(btnTxt??"",
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3.copyWith(color: ColorResources.COLOR_WHITE, fontSize: Dimensions.FONT_SIZE_LARGE)),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Show more of your code, your ```CustomButton```.  You want to sum the prices of your products when you press the button?

Comment: i pull the total product in my code. I just want to parse the double data and show it in the button.

Comment: widget.amount.toString(), I want to print 'total amount' and '500', how should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                //   height: 100,
                                width: 185,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL),
                                child: CustomButton(
                                btnTxt: getTranslated('t_amount', context) + PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, widget.amount),
                                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          ),
                          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this code can help you, to display the total number inside the button child `Text` you just use the `$` sign. If this is not what you are trying to do comment so I can update the code.

```
double totalValue = getTotal();  // getting the price example
Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                            //   height: 100,
                            width: 150,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
                            child: CustomButton(
                            btnTxt: 'Total: $totalValue',
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,

          ),
          ),
```

Comment: btnTxt: getTranslated('t_amount', context) + PriceConverter.convertPrice(context, widget.amount), That's how I did it and solved it later, thanks.